# How do I know when an NSManagedObject will be deleted from the persistent store?

Tags: ios, core-data

So, for the purposes of saving space and caching, I defined a `Photo` model in CoreData that has an attribute `imageDataURL` (a fileURL).

This data would be stored in the Documents directory.  As such, I want to make sure I am cleaning up that data if the user deletes the `Photo` object.

My question is, where should I look to have a `deleteDataAtImageURL(...)` method?

I'm thinking it would be in the `prepareForDeletion()` method on `NSManagedObject` and I check if that object's context's *parent* is `nil`.  This tells me that it is a context directly in contact with the Persistent Store.

This should work, unless of course the user resets the context and doesn't save it.

I can't imagine I'm the first one to want to do this, so any advice on this approach (or a better one!) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution for me was to override prepareForDeletion and check if the the object's `.managedObjectContext.parent` property is nil.  That tells me that it's connected to the PersistentStore, and there I can do the task I want to.

I don't know if this is best practices, but it is working.

I believe the above answer from sschale would also work although I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Here's how I solved it by using a NotificationCenter observer for an action on my root saving context.

```
//done as part of a singleton class setup
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SingletonClass.handleModelDataChange), name:NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: yourRootSavingContext)

internal func handleModelDataChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    //get documents directory
    let documentsURL = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    //get deleted items from dictionary
    if let deleted = notification.userInfo?[NSDeletedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> , deleted.count > 0 {
      for object in deleted{
        //sort out your objects of interest, I cared about objects of a certain class
        if ...{
          do {
            //delete filepath
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(myPathComponent, isDirectory: true))
            //print("Deleted the folder \(documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(myPathComponent, isDirectory: true))")
          }
          catch {
            //print("I tried :(")
            print(error)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's IF you have a root saving context.  I'm using the latest iOS 10 boilerplate (NSPersistentContainer).  I guess that would be my root saving context.  I'd ideally like the model to take care of its own cleanup.  It's better encapsulation.